# Create a spring session in amqp rpc client

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-session

I developped spring remoting amqp rpc applications.

That's works well for methods that don't use bean with Scope SESSION.

For the other methods, the client can't use spring session, and I get this exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.userSession': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:362) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at io.kzreactive.akwtype.akwtypeback.common.service.UserSession$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55d53e95.setUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.kzreactive.akwtype.akwtypeback.engine.service.AppService.login(AppService.kt:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:215) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:39) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at io.kzreactive.akwtype.akwtypeback.gateway.rabbitmq.SessionDefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(RabbitMQSession.kt:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:114) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.remoting.service.AmqpInvokerServiceExporter.onMessage(AmqpInvokerServiceExporter.java:80) [spring-amqp-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1457) [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324) [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303) [spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:785) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:769) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1010) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:55) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:350) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

So I would create and use a spring session over rabbit mq

First, I managed to pass the sessionId in RPC call

on the server I add an attribute

```
class SessionDefaultRemoteInvocationFactory : DefaultRemoteInvocationFactory() {

    override fun createRemoteInvocation(methodInvocation: MethodInvocation?): RemoteInvocation {
        return super.createRemoteInvocation(methodInvocation)
                .apply { addAttribute("sessionId", RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().sessionId) }
    }
}
```

on the client I can read it

```
class SessionDefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor : DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor() {

    override fun invoke(invocation: RemoteInvocation?, targetObject: Any?): Any {

        if (invocation is RemoteInvocation) {
            invocation.getAttribute("sessionId")?.let {

                val sessionId = it.toString()

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = AnonymousAuthenticationToken(sessionId,
                        "anonymousUser", listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")))

                val attr = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() as ServletRequestAttributes // <= ERROR here
                attr.request.getSession(true)
            }
        }

        return super.invoke(invocation, targetObject)
    }
}
```

but I don't manage to use it to create a spring session

How can I create a spring session in this NON http context

I tried to create a request context listener

```
@Configuration
@WebListener
class MyRequestContextListener : RequestContextListener()
```

but same error

Comment: I think you need to take a look into Spring Session project and try to restore HTTP session somehow using the shared store. Although I'm fully not sure that it is going to be possible since you don't have any HTTP context on the client at all: https://spring.io/projects/spring-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment I bypass the spring session and I inject a bean with the same behavior

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
class EngineThread(var engineSession: ThreadLocal<EngineSession> = ThreadLocal()) : IEngineSession by engineSession.getOrSet( { EngineSession() })

@Component
@Profile("engine & !test")
class SessionDefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor(val engineThread: EngineThread) : DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor() {

    val engineSessionStore : MutableMap<String, EngineSession> = mutableMapOf()

    override fun invoke(invocation: RemoteInvocation?, targetObject: Any?): Any {

        if (invocation is RemoteInvocation) {
            invocation.getAttribute(SESSION_ID)?.let {

                val sessionId = it.toString()

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = AnonymousAuthenticationToken(sessionId,
                        "anonymousUser", listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")))

                if (! engineSessionStore.contains(sessionId)) {
                    engineSessionStore.put(sessionId, EngineSession())
                }
                engineThread.engineSession.set(engineSessionStore.getValue(sessionId))

            }
        }

        return super.invoke(invocation, targetObject)
    }
}
```

The job is done but I'm not very well with this solution
(I will add clean by softreference… but all this work is reinvent session instead of use spring session)